# Understanding virtual machine memory allocation and process virtual memory - Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, virtual-memory

I am trying to understand how the memory demands of my application are imposed on a virtual machine and/or the host computer. The context of this question is Windows 10 guest O/S on (probably) Windows Server 2016 using Hyper-V.

If I run my 64-bit application on a physical Windows 10 computer (has 32GB RAM), the process it executes in will peak at about 10GB virtual memory and will function successfully.
The application was run on a VM (which I learned after the fact only had 4GB allocated to the guest O/S) and the application failed. I am assuming it failed due to memory exhaustion, but there is no diagnostic to confirm this.

Since the application is executing in process virtual memory, it should not be limited by physical memory available (even though the host system should have plenty). I would expect the 4GB allocation to the VM to be a constraint on physical memory usage, so should not limit the virtual memory availabe to any process executing in the VM, correct? Or does the VM's memory allocation actually manifest in a limit on virtual memory available to a process executing in the VM? Does the VM's memory allocation need to be selected such that it will satisfy an application's virtual memory requirements?

Comment: How much virtual memory was the guest operating system allowed exactly?  You should [edit] your question to include this information.  What OS was the guest OS running?

Answer (score 2):

In any operating system, the total virtual memory available is the sum of the RAM
and the swap-file.

It is unlikely that a VM or a computer with 4 GB of RAM would have allocated
a swap-file of at least 6 GB, which would complete the 10 GB that are required
by your application. So once it was exhausted, additional memory requests
would fail.

You should also take into account the memory required by the operating system
of the VM, the required cache memory for disk access, and more.

In any case, having most of the virtual memory residing in the swap-file is
pretty bad for performance. The VM risks doing nothing but swap operation
of memory pages in and out of RAM, so thrashing the disk.

Comment: I thoroughly understand the points about swap files, swapping and thrashing. What was not clear to me was the size constraint on the swap file. I thought the Windows swapfile could grow dynamically and was thus constrained by available disk.

Comment: No, it is preallocated in *Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced > Performance Settings > Advanced > Virtual memory Change*. Well squirreled away, but it's there.